# Portal to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've found this [example](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/yzMaBd) on official site which describes how to use `portal`. In this example is being created new **'root'** div for modals with use of `ReactDOM.createPortal()`. Is there a way to teleport component to another component (not just different root).

*It might not be done with `portal` - I just thought it might be useful for this solution*

---

**I am trying to 'extend' Navigation with button which has logic dependency on MyComponentA or MyComponentB** (different button, different behaviour directed by different component but placed in DOM of navigation).

This is simplified example of what I am trying to achieve:

**App**

This is root component of my application which includes Navigation, MyComponentA and MyComponentB

```
class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
       return (
          <Navigation/>
          <MyComponentA/>
          <MyComponentB/>
       );
    }
}
```

**Navigation**

This is component where I want to place output of portal.

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <OutputOfPortal>
            {/* I want to teleport something here from another component */}
         </OutputOfPortal>
      );
   }
}
```

**MyComponentA**

This is component where I want to place source for portal. Same situation as for MyComponentB but with different content.

```
class MyComponentA extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         {/* Another code */}
         <InputOfPortal>
            {/* I want to teleport something from here to navigation */}
            <button onClick={this.functionInThisComponent}> click me </button>
         </InputOfPortal>
         {/* Another code */}
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: If it's already under your root component element you don't need to (and probably shouldn't) use a portal. Only use a portal to escape the root component element. Why not just do `<Navigation><MyComponentA /></Navigation>` ?

Comment: @apokryfos I don't want to include whole component into it but just 'teleport' part of my component. It means to 'extend' my navigation with buttons which has logic placed in MyComponentA and different button and different logic in MyComponentB (but still placed in DOM of navigation).

Comment: You can probably do what you need by just doing some modularisation of your current code architecture. I would not encourage you try to get a portal to work the way you want since it most likely will need to be very hacky to reconcile real DOM with virutal DOM elements.

Comment: @apokryfos By modularisation you mean replacing functions on different place (like 'functionInThisComponent' in my example)? I am looking for something what could be able to place rendered DOM element in different component but keeps logic inside of another.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to have some state in your App component that will be passed to Navigation component as props/children, then pass some event handlers into your MyComponentA and MyComponentB, that will update the state on how Navigation should behave

Comment: Take a look at [react-singleton](https://github.com/peterbee/react-singleton) you might be able to use that and just re-use the same component markup in both places and get the same component behaviour

Comment: @andymccullough How do you mean it? Like `state: { navBtns: [] }` in my `App` which would be set in `MyComponentA` like `this.props.setBtnToState(<button onClick={this.function}/>)`? Am I allowed to pass whole components to the state and would it keep references and right functions?

Answer (score 1):

I've set id `navigation-controls` to element in `Navigation`. Than I've created another component named `NavigationExtension` which is used as a portal to `Navigation`. Every children of this portal keeps his functionality in original component where it has been created.

**Navigation**

I've just created `div` with id in place where I want to teleport.

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
        // some code ... 
        <div id="navigation-controls">
            // some buttons ... 
        </div>
        // some code ...
      );
   }
}
```

**NavigationExtension**

This will teleport anything what is wrapped inside to navigation

```
class NavExtension extends React.Component
{
    el = document.createElement("div");

    componentDidMount() {
        // nav element is selected here by id
        this.targetEl = document.getElementById("navigation-controls");
        this.targetEl.appendChild(this.el);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.targetEl.removeChild(this.el);
    }

    render() {
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <React.Fragment>
                {this.props.children}
            </React.Fragment>, this.el);
    }
}
```

**MyComponentA**

Finally declaring my buttons and teleporting them to the navigation.

```
class MyComponentA extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         // some code ...
         <NavigationExtension>
            <button onClick={this.functionInThisComponent}> I'm in navigation! </button>
         </NavigationExtension>
         // some code ...
      );
   }
}
```

I'm not sure if I just didn't understand another answers but this is exactly what I've wanted.

Answer (score 0):

- i think u forget to use **render()** method
- you have to use react router dom if i undestand right what u want https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom
- and you have to use props and send your props with react router dom
- usualy u use a layout page for put there the navBar and than in the same page u add the ***props.childern*** to render the page under the navbar

  ```
  import React, { Component } from "react";
  import NavBar from "./NavBar"
  class Layout extends Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  }

  render(){
  return (
    <div>
        <NavBar/>

    <div className="container">
      {this.props.children}
    </div>


    </div>

  );
  }}

  export default Layout;
  ```
- here is the example for reacr router dom

  ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import Layout from "./components/layout/Layout"
   import { Switch,Route } from "react-router-dom";
   import DashBoard from './components/dashboard/DashBoard'
   import ShopDetails from './components/shops/ShopDetails'
   import SignIn from './components/auth/SignIn'
   import CreateShop from './components/shops/CreateShop'
   import CreateProduct from './components/shops/CreateProduct'
   import './App.css';

   class App extends Component { 
      render(){
        const route=(
         <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={DashBoard} />
            <Route path="/shop/:id" component={ShopDetails} />
            <Route  path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
            <Route  path="/createshop" component={CreateShop} />
            <Route  path="/createproduct" component={CreateProduct} />
            {/* <Route  path="/login" component={Login} />
           <Route  path="/shoppage" component={ShopPage} /> */}
        </Switch>
      )
    return (
    <Layout>
      {route}
    </Layout>);}}
  export default App;
  ```

after that u can go to the route u want with your path
some like localhost3000/ 
localhost3000/signin
localhost3000/user/:id

Comment: Yea you are right I've forgot `render` in this simplified example. Fixed now. Thank you for your answer but layout isn't that thing which I am looking for.

Comment: the layout just for example how you should use react-router-dom
check it cus this the way to render couple of pages

Comment: Well I am using router but it doesn't `teleport` my component with all his behavior into the parent/sibling component.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html 
here in react portal they did the same what i try to explane you by react router dom
they use props.children

Comment: Thank you for your patience. This article is the one which I've mentioned in question but I am not sure how could it help me to 'port' component to the sibling component of parent. My functions are placed much deeper than in router or something above.

Comment: this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/template',
  search: '?query=abc',
  state: { detail: response.data }
})

Answer (score 0):

I have a top panel with `position:sticky` and I sometimes needed to add page-specific controls to the sticky area. The only solution was to somehow "teleport" those controls to the top. Here is how I did it:

```
<StickyProvider>

  <StickyRender>
    <nav>this is always rendered</nav>
    {/* <- other components will get "teleported" here... */}
  </StickyRender>
  
  <Sticky className='add-this-classname-to-top'>
    <span>this will not be render here, but as child of StickyRender</span>
  </Sticky>
 
  ...
  
  <Sticky>
    <span>this will be also added atop</span>
  </Sticky>

  <StickyRender/> {/* We can even duplicate everything here */}

</StickyProvider>
```

###### `StickyHeader.tsx`

```
import React, { createContext, PropsWithChildren, useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { contextFallbackFunction } from 'src/utils'

/**
 * @author Qwerty <qwerty@qwerty.xyz>
 *
 * These components allow you to collect children from any part of the tree and render them elsewhere.
 *
 * - `<StickyProvider/>` - context
 * - `<Sticky/>` - wrap your components
 * - `<StickyRender/>` - your components will appear here
 *
 * *note* You can use multiple `<Sticky/>` in multiple places. You can also use multiple `<StickyRender/>` to duplicate children.
 *
 * @example
 * <StickyProvider>
 *   <StickyRender>
 *     <nav>always rendered</nav>
 *   </StickyRender>
 *
 *   <Sticky>
 *     <span>this will not be render here, but as child of StickyRender</span>
 *   </Sticky>
 * </StickyProvider>
 */

// Sticky --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

interface StickyProps {
  /**
   * You need to provide the height of the **whole** sticky area, including `--nav-height` and margins!
   * e.g.
   * - `[--sticky-height:calc(96px+var(--nav-height)+40px)]`
   * - `md:![--sticky-height:248px] ![--sticky-height:152px]`
   *
   * *note:* It might be necessary to use `!` to override default value.
   */
  className: string
}

/**
 * This component *"consumes"* children and passes them through context to a `<RenderSticky/>` component,
 * which renders them to a different location, allowing us to glue them to a separate dom subtree - necessary for isolating scroll.
 */
export const Sticky: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<StickyProps>> = ({ children, className }) => {
  const ref = useRef<Children>(null)
  ref.current = children

  const { setRefEffect, setClassNameEffect, forceUpdate } = useSetStickyContext()

  useEffect(() => setRefEffect(ref), []) // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  useEffect(() => setClassNameEffect(className), [className]) // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  // Fallback to render children if <Sticky/> is used without its Context.
  if (setRefEffect === contextFallbackFunction) return <>{children}</>
  forceUpdate()
  return null
}

// RenderSticky --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * This is where all Sticky children are rendered to.
 */
export const StickyRender: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<StickyProps>> = ({ children, className: className_ }) => {
  const { className, childrenRefs } = useGetStickyChildren()
  return (
    <header id='Sticky' className={`sticky top-0 z-10 ${className_} ${className}`}>
      {children}
      {childrenRefs.map((ref) => ref.current)}
    </header>
  )
}

// Context -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Children = AllowArray<React.ReactNode>
type ChildrenRef = React.MutableRefObject<Children>

interface GetStickyContext {
  childrenRefs: ChildrenRef[]
  className: string
}

interface SetStickyContext {
  setRefEffect: (childrenRef: ChildrenRef) => () => void
  setClassNameEffect: (
    /**
     * e.g. `md:![--sticky-height:40px] ![--sticky-height:var(--nav-height)]`
     *
     * *note:* It might be necessary to use `!` to override style provided from <RenderSticky/>'s className.
     */
    className: string) => () => void
  forceUpdate: () => void
}

const defaultGetStickyContext: GetStickyContext = {
  childrenRefs: [],
  className: '',
}

const defaultSetStickyContext: SetStickyContext = {
  setRefEffect: contextFallbackFunction,
  setClassNameEffect: contextFallbackFunction,
  forceUpdate: contextFallbackFunction,
}

const GetStickyContext = createContext<GetStickyContext>(defaultGetStickyContext)
const useGetStickyChildren = () => useContext(GetStickyContext)

const SetStickyContext = createContext<SetStickyContext>(defaultSetStickyContext)
const useSetStickyContext = () => useContext(SetStickyContext)

// Provider ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export const StickyProvider: React.FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {
  const [childrenRefs, setChildrenRefs] = useState<ChildrenRef[]>([])
  const [className, setClassName] = useState('')

  const [shouldUpdate, forceUpdate] = React.useReducer(() => ({}), {})

  /* This callback returns a cleaning function for `useEffect`. */
  const setRefEffect: SetStickyContext['setRefEffect'] = useCallback((ref) => {
    setChildrenRefs((prev) => prev.includes(ref) ? prev : [...prev, ref])
    return () => setChildrenRefs((prev, ix = prev.indexOf(ref)) => ix >= 0 ? [...prev.slice(0, ix), ...prev.slice(ix + 1)] : prev)
  }, [])

  /* This callback returns a cleaning function for `useEffect`. */
  const setClassNameEffect: SetStickyContext['setClassNameEffect'] = useCallback((className_) => {
    setClassName(className_)
    return () => setClassName('')
  }, [])

  const valueSetSticky = useMemo(() => ({ setRefEffect, setClassNameEffect, forceUpdate }), [setRefEffect, setClassNameEffect, forceUpdate])
  const valueGetSticky = useMemo(() => ({ childrenRefs, className }), [childrenRefs, className, shouldUpdate]) // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  return (
    <SetStickyContext.Provider value={valueSetSticky}>
      <GetStickyContext.Provider value={valueGetSticky}>
        {children}
      </GetStickyContext.Provider>
    </SetStickyContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

###### `src/utils.ts`

```
export function contextFallbackFunction(...any: any[]): any { console.error('You cannot use this context without Provider!') }
```